# Need some assistance in creating a view definition

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a view as follows :

```
CREATE VIEW TEMP_VIEW AS
SELECT
   a.actor_id,
   a.first_name,
   a.last_name,
   LISTAGG(DISTINCT(c.name ) || ': ' ||
        (SELECT LISTAGG(f.title,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f.title)
                    FROM film f
                    INNER JOIN film_category fc
                      ON f.film_id = fc.film_id
                    INNER JOIN film_actor fa
                      ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
                    WHERE fc.category_id = c.category_id
                    AND fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
                 )
             ,'; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.name) AS film_info
FROM actor a
LEFT JOIN film_actor fa ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
LEFT JOIN film_category fc ON fa.film_id = fc.film_id
LEFT JOIN category c ON fc.category_id = c.category_id
GROUP BY a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name;
```

The error I am getting is :

> LISTAGG(DISTINCT(c.name ) || ': ' ||
>      *
>   ERROR at line 5:
>   ORA-30482: DISTINCT option not allowed for this function

The query output of the view should be like :

```
actor_id   | 1
first_name | PENELOPE
last_name  | GUINESS
film_info  | Animation: ANACONDA CONFESSIONS; Children: LANGUAGE COWBOY; Classics: COLOR PHILADELPHIA, WESTWARD SEABISCUIT; Comedy: VERTIGO NORTHWEST; Documentary: ACADEMY DINOSAUR; Family: KING EVOLUTION, SPLASH GUMP; Foreign: MULHOLLAND BEAST; Games: BULWORTH COMMANDMENTS, HUMAN GRAFFITI; Horror: ELEPHANT TROJAN, LADY STAGE, RULES HUMAN; Music: WIZARD COLDBLOODED; New: ANGELS LIFE, OKLAHOMA JUMANJI; Sci-Fi: CHEAPER CLYDE; Sports: GLEAMING JAWBREAKER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.1 - The error message is quite clear, you cannot use DISTINCT function within LISTAGG.

No.2 - In a normalized data structure, a category name will always be unique

Try and check it yourself :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(name)) FROM category;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM category;
```

If your schema is properly normalized the results will be the same for both queries, if so take out the word  DISTINCT from your view definition.

The rest looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with nested selects.  I think the following does what you want:

```
SELECT actor_id, first_name, last_name,
       LISTAGG(category || ': ' || films, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY category)
FROM (SELECT a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name, c.name as category
             LISTAGG(f.title, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f.title) as films
      FROM actor a LEFT JOIN
           film_actor fa
           ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id LEFT JOIN
           file f
           on fa.film_id = f.film_id LEFT JOIN
           film_category fc
           ON fa.film_id = fc.film_id LEFT JOIN
           category c
           ON fc.category_id = c.category_id
      GROUP BY a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name, c.name
     ) t
GROUP BY actor_id, first_name, last_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would select the distinct records first and then use listagg function. Something like this

```
create table test1 ( col1 number, col2 number);

insert into test1 values (1,2);
insert into test1 values (1,2);
insert into test1 values (1,2);
insert into test1 values (2,3);
insert into test1 values (2,3);
insert into test1 values (3,4);
commit;


select LISTAGG(col1, ',') within group ( order by col2) as str
from (select distinct col1,col2 from test1);
```